# Asus X571 notebook shutting down because critical temperature is reached (99°C)

Tags: 20.04, cpu, fan, overheating, temperature

It has happened several times that my notebook suddenly switches off due to the CPU reaching critical temperature, as can be seen in the log. Strange, however, that the CPU fan is not already running at maximum speed at these moments, but quietly and at a lower speed, and it seems to me that the fan does not get faster in time.

I have already cleaned the notebook from dust thoroughly (it wasn't much), and the only other thing left to do is maybe apply better heat conduction to the CPU, but that would be a lot of work!

Here is an example of the last log entries when a shutdown happened:

```
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.061201] mce: CPU6: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 202)
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.061201] mce: CPU2: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 202)
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.061202] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 567)
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.061203] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 567)
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.061204] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 567)
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.061206] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 567)
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.061206] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 567)
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.061207] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 567)
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.061208] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 567)
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.061208] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 567)
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.062179] mce: CPU2: Core temperature/speed normal
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.062179] mce: CPU6: Core temperature/speed normal
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.062180] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.062181] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.062182] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.062183] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.062183] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.062184] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.062184] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
Oct  5 19:17:00 Abook kernel: [64328.062185] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
Oct  5 19:17:01 Abook CRON[67310]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct  5 19:18:07 Abook rtkit-daemon[1851]: Supervising 9 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Oct  5 19:19:00 Abook kernel: [64448.077575] thermal thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached (99 C), shutting down
```

Is it possible to influence the behavior of the fan and make it react more quickly to a rise in temperature?

Comment: If your computer is overheating, there might be a bigger hardware issue. Often, the computer manufacturer (Asus, in your case), might provide software to adjust the computer and fan settings. Or, and this is probobly easier because you are using Ubuntu, if you go into the BIOS, there is often settings for the fan. Sometimes it is just something basic like performance or quiet mode (select performance for better cooling), but sometimes you can adjust the fan curve to make the fan run sooner and faster. Of course, you might need to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: There is no BIOS setting for fan control, only the MyASUS tool on Windows has an option to choose "Performance" or "Standard" fan setting. I changed this to "Performance" (using Dual Boot) but I don't really think this can have any effect when I reboot to Ubuntu. I am still getting shutdowns because of high temperature, often while system updates are running & while the fan is only running at low speed.
Recently the Windows 10 21H2 update performed without problems while the fan was running at maximum speed all the time.
I think the problem is fan control, it should speed up earlier.

Comment: Then I suggest contacting Asus customer support, as if there is no BIOS or app that can do it, this is not a Ubuntu issue. By default, barring something strange like overclocking, _a laptop should not overheat_. This is not something that random internet strangers can fix. You need to either contact support or get a professional computer technician to take a look.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

I am encountering this issue as well since a few week ago.. It seems like the dual fan doesn't get going anymore tried a few things but doesn't look like anything is working right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately the problem is solved since I have updated to the recent BIOS version 311 for Asus X571.

It also seems that it was introduced with BIOS version 310. The problems started a while after I updated to version 310, which was the current version at that time.
After updating to BIOS version 311 the overheating shutdown problem is gone!